# Create file with specific permisions in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-permissions, nsfilemanager

In my project i'm creating a file using the function:

```
- (BOOL)createFileAtPath:(NSString *)path contents:(NSData *)data attributes:(NSDictionary *)attr;
```

I want to grant this file permissions so only the user can read and write (-rw------).
I cant figure out (or find documentation) how i should fill this attribute dictionary (keys and values).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who are you protecting the file from?

Comment: I am building SDK and i want it to be the only one who reads and write to a specific file. don't want other to be able to do it

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=protect+the+file+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=udHQU7uREIbV8geoi4GwCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you expect to gain from this, but the syntax is:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSFilePosixPermissions : @((short)(0x600))
};
BOOL created = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                       contents:data
                                                     attributes:attributes];
```

Not sure if you actually need the `(short)` cast or not.

Comment: It's not that important, but i still want to play it on the safe side. can you tell me where can you find documentation for it?
Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:

Comment: Shouldn't the value be `0600`, not `0x600`? You want the octal value `600`, not the hex value `600`. There's a big difference.